# Filtering from list of C# or LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, model

I am trying to filter from attachList the taxheaderID, it comes from my database which is structured as such.

```
public int attachmentID { get; set; }
public int headerID { get; set; }
public string uploadedfilename { get; set; }
public string originalfilename { get; set; }
public string foldername { get; set; }
```

Here is the code that gets data from the database:

```
public JsonResult GetAllAttach()
{
    using (car_monitoringEntities contextObj = new car_monitoringEntities())
    {
        var attachList = contextObj.car_taxcomputationattachment.ToList();
        return Json(attachList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

These are my attempts:

```
attachList
    .Select(x => x.headerID)
    .Where(x => x == x)
    .Take(1);
```

and:

```
attachList = attachList
    .Where(al => attachList
        .Any(alx => al.taxheaderID == alx.headerID 
                 && al.headerID == alx.headerID));
```

The problem is I want to parse multiple attach on a single headerID or filter them base on headerID. For example:

Problem to fix:

[This is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6utw3.png)

Desired output: 
[Combined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDxm6.png)

data table: 
[data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irY4c.png)
[data table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW4Y0.png)

Here is the actual solution that was made to get the output, but my coworker told me that it is not a good practice that's why I'm trying to filter it in the function itself. apologies for the trouble, thanks!

```
<div ng-repeat="att in attach|filter:{headerID:header.headerID}:true">

      <a href="~/UploadedFiles/{{att.uploadedfilename}}" download="{{att.uploadedfilename}}" target="_blank">{{att.uploadedfilename}} <br /></a>

 </div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to filter the attachment list on header id (and header id is actually the file name?).

Comment: @SalomonZhang I've edited the post and included the problem that I wanted to fix at the bottom which should give a clear idea

Comment: @peeyushsingh my bad, I've posted the wrong database, please see the new changes. headerID should be the reference, the filename is as such, uploadedfilename

Comment: I posted an answer to get all attachments by Id.

Comment: your desired output is two list or some combination of one list?

Comment: both data table images are same....and you have two different output images....

Comment: @peeyushsingh my apologies, I've fixed the photo and added more details

Comment: You need to create a nested view model. What is your domain model named?

Comment: updated my ans, look at the 3rd query...you are not looking to filter at all from what I see, simply selecting a subset of properties from your existing ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get attachments by Id

```
public JsonResult GetAllAttach(int headerId)
{
    using (car_monitoringEntities contextObj = new car_monitoringEntities())
    {
        var attachList = contextObj.car_taxcomputationattachment
                                   .Where(x => x.headerID == headerId)
                                   .ToList();
        return Json(attachList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

If you want to have all data in one JSON result, then you need to create a nested view model.

Comment: tried this just now, it still shows the problem, I've added another image at the bottom which might make it more clear, thank you

Comment: tried this but it doesn't work, the headerID reference also comes from the database. I've added more details, apologies for the inconvenience

Comment: am I missing something here, your `where` clause `x.headerID == x.headerID` should always evaluate to true? Then why have the where?

Comment: @peeyushsingh That was a typo. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the header id on which you want to filter in a local variable, you are almost correct

```
int headerIdToFind = 19;
// think of x as a local variable inside a foreach loop which
// iterates over each item in the attachList (it does not exist 
// outside the where method)
// this is what you got wrong when you compared the item to itself
var filteredAttach = attachList.Where(x => x.headerId = headerIdToFind);

// if you want to select only some properties based on header id
// you can use select to project those properties
var filteredAttach = attachList.Where(x => x.headerId = headerIdToFind).
                      Select(x => new {x.attachmentId, x.folderName});

// based on last image, you only want to select (project) header id and the 
// filename. so you do not need where (filter) at all
// you can put all the properties you need in the select clause
var filteredAttach = attachList.Select(x => new {x.headerId, x.attachmentId});
// you can enumerate the filtered attach list of convert it into a list 
var filteredAttach = filteredAttach.ToList();
```

Comment: i have not set the header id as a local variable, but would like to filter it on the JsonResult function itself, is there any way to do that? I've added another image at the bottom which might make it more clear, thank you